# How to make vimrc settings applicable for a directory tree only

Tags: vimrc

Is there a way to make certain vimrc configuration valid only for files under a defined directory tree? Or alternatively, is there a way to have a .vimrc file in a directory, and make its setting override all $HOME/.vimrc for that directory and subdirectories (and maybe, additional vimrc file in subdirectory would override again what was overridden by the directory-tree-root vimrc) ?

Like this:

```
- ~
+- .vimrc
+- Development
   +- proj
      +- src 
         +- .vimrc (overrides ~/.vimrc for files in Development/proj/src and subdirs)
      +- res
         +- .vimrc (overrides ~/.vimrc for files in Development/proj/res and subdirs)
         +- cc
            +- .vimrc (overrides ../.vimrc and ~/.vimrc for files in Development/proj/res/cc)
```

Comment: You are aware that a vimrc can do anything? e.g., it can execute arbitrary commands such as `rm -Rf $HOME`. You do *not* want to source an untrusted vimrc.

Comment: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=441

Comment: @derobert I am not very concerned with that; if someone breaks in and drops a random .vimrc, well he did already breakin end of the day; if it is stuff coming from a src control repo, and i pull or rebase without noticing, then it would be _me_ to blame, like downloading a random piece of software, make and execute.

Comment: Related: [Vim: apply settings on files in directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/456792/vim-apply-settings-on-files-in-directory) at stackoverflow SE

Comment: @Carpetsmoker thanks, definitely a duplicate; should i delete or wait for close votes?

Comment: @guido I don't think you can delete this question due to it having answers, but you can add close votes to your own question (I once did that on SO, anyway)... In any case, the question is still useful, many people will search for *"How to make vimrc settings applicable for a directory tree only"*, and not for *"How to make vimrc settings applicable for a project only"*; so it's useful as an "entry point" to the canonical question. This is why duplicates are never removed :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker it seems i can delete (even if there is an accepted answer, weird); probably i cannot vote because i haven't enough reputation. Please do if you can, actually the question wording is quite different so it may still be worthy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

As you specified `directory tree`, it excludes the `.exrc` approach (as it only works for one directory), and the *modelines* as well.

Remains the hand-rolled way: you put an autocommand in your `.vimrc` for pattern or specific directories. It's not my preferred approach as it clutters the `.vimrc` with yet another thing -- and also because my mind have been compromised with the `Single Responsibility Principle`.

For reference, there is also the plugin *Project* -- one of the oldest on vim.org. As I'm not using it, I won't detail how it works.

Then, there are many, and many, plugins with a name that looks like *local vimrc*. I've even been maintaining one for years: https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc

Regarding its features,

- It answers your question: being sourced for each file in a hierarchy -- actually each time we enter a related vim window, the matching `_vimrc_local` file*s* are sourced.
- The plugin will look for files named `_vimrc_local.vim`, though the pattern used to search for files can be configured (as a string or a list of patterns)
- It permit plugins that uses per project settings to force loading the `_vimrc_local` file before anything else. For instance, when I run `gvim foobar.cpp` from the shell my template expander plugin (TEP) ([mu-template](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/muTemplate)) automatically fills in the project name, the project style (copyright headers, namespaces, naming conventions, ...). As TEP and `vimrc_local` plugins usually use the same vim event, there is a race on the event, and there is no guaranty project settings can be loaded before expanding any template. So, there is a way with my plugin to fix this kind of races.
- On the official site, you'll found some explanations on how to write the `_vimrc_local.vim` project files.
- It's being regularly tested and used on Windows (with/without cygwin), *nixes.
- It stops searching for project configuration at $HOME, or the root directory (`/`, `//ip/`), or don't even try to on remote files (http, ftp, ...).
- It supports black and white lists, and also ask-to-the-user and sandbox lists which will work in the same way: what is done of the project-file will depend on the kind the list the project-file belongs to.
- Someday, I'll eventually have [templates to generate project configurations](https://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/wiki/BTW) for C & C++ project managed with/without CMake, generating (or not) Doxygen documentation, ...

Comment: +1 ... Does your local-vimrc plugin prevent some of the security issues that could happen? For example, I often download or checkout the source of a project (including small ones) to investigate something. *Anyone* could put a `.localvimrc` in that, and do all sorts of evil stuff, or other, non-malicious, harmful things, like maybe `system('rm -rf /$HOME/$UNDEFINED_ON_MY_SYSTEM')` or some such...

Comment: Yes and No, it does nothing to prevent to code to execute. However, you could force the pattern searched (`g:local_vimrc`) to something that makes no sense as you are opening vim. This will require some knowledge about how to launch vim with parameters. I guess, I'd better add blacklists and such to permit to emulate sandboxes. This would be easier to open files from unsecured projects. My next _eventual_ course of action for this plugin was to permit to support `vimrc_local` outside of the current directory.

Comment: Fixed. Now, blacklists & co are supported.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the LocalVimrc plugin with success, very handy indeed!

https://github.com/embear/vim-localvimrc

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer according to [site standards](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/99/24).