# Is there a way to use different vimrc file for different directory?

Tags: vimrc

I want to use different config files for different directories. For example, if I want to use different plugins(via a plugin manager) or use different color themes. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: I think you could probably get away with setting the VIMINIT variable to adjust the runtimepath based on the current directory. Or even do that in your vimrc. And use plugin/ files for the custom stuff

Comment: I think [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4721/1841) I asked a few years ago could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use any [local vimrc plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc) as long as your plugin manager supports on-the-fly loading of plugins.

The almost related Q/A here is missing a few contestants: [How to make vimrc settings applicable for a directory tree only](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/how-to-make-vimrc-settings-applicable-for-a-directory-tree-only/2134#2134). The one on SO is a little bit more complete: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456792/vim-apply-settings-on-files-in-directory/456889#456889

Note that we cannot use different colorthemes simultaneously in a same vim session. At best the colortheme would change every time you jump into a buffer from a different project -- it would quickly become annoying IMO.